# Unable to click the anchor tags for the second time

Tags: c#, watin, mshtml, pdf-scraping

I am writing an scraping program.

The very first time i am able to click the anchor tags, But once I again loop in the same doesn't happen. I have done this in the Watin instance of IE. I doubt this is because of the back of the IE instance which i Have done.

Please find the two pieces of code.

Downloading the PDF's method

```
private void DownloadFiles(IE ieInstance, HTMLDocument document_sub)
{
  // int chktest = 2;
  try
  {
    foreach (HTMLAnchorElement anchorTagPg1 in document_sub.getElementsByTagName("a"))
    {
      if (anchorTagPg1.innerText.Contains("Monthly Statement"))
      {
        string urltemp = anchorTagPg1.outerHTML.ToString();
        int startTextpos = urltemp.IndexOf("window.open");
        string spltstr1 = urltemp.Substring(startTextpos);
        int endpos = spltstr1.IndexOf(')');
        string spltstr2 = spltstr1.Substring(0, endpos);
        spltstr2 = spltstr2.Replace("window.open(", "");
        string[] manipulatestrsplt = spltstr2.Split(',');
        string finalmanipstr = manipulatestrsplt[0].Replace("'", "");
        finalmanipstr = finalmanipstr.Replace("amp;", "");
        finalurl = "https://myaccount.pseg.com/psegbdisu/" + finalmanipstr;
        //anchorTagPg1.click();
        //ieInstance.WaitForComplete();
        ieInstance.GoToNoWait(finalurl);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("^%S"); // to get the Save As window...
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("abc123");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.Send("^S");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("DownloadedFile" + iFileCnt + ".pdf");  // Enters File Name
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        iFileCnt++;
        //chktest++;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ieInstance.Back();
        // bool rtnBack = ieInstance.Back();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        // }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
  }
}
```

Another Method where in which I am not able to hit the anchor tag, nor able to raise onclick event.

```
private void ClickSelectAccount(IE ieInstance)
{
  FrameCollection hframesSelAcct = ieInstance.Frames;
  HTMLDocument document_sub_SelAcct = ((mshtml.HTMLDocument)(((WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEDocument)(((WatiN.Core.FrameCollection)(hframesSelAcct))[1].NativeDocument)).HtmlDocument));

  foreach (HTMLAnchorElement anchorTagSelectAcct in document_sub_SelAcct.getElementsByTagName("a"))
  {
    if (anchorTagSelectAcct.innerText.Contains("Select Account"))
    {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      //anchorTagSelectAcct.click();
      anchorTagSelectAcct.FireEvent("onclick");
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
      ieInstance.WaitForComplete();
      anchorTagSelectAcct.click();
      Thread.Sleep(10000);

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Can please someone help me, the first time the second method works fine but not second time. I have a doubt with the IE instance, as i have tried with more sleep time, and also its able to go in the loop but just not able to click the links.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following inside your DownloadFiles method:

```
var link = ieInstance.Links.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Text.Equals("Select Account"));
if (link != null && link.Exists)
{
   link.Click();
}
```

or

```
var link = ieInstance.Links.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Text.Equals("Monthly Statement"));
if (link != null && link.Exists)
{
   link.Click();
}
```

Debug this code to see that you are actually getting inside the link.Exists if statement. If you are not you should try:

```
var links = browser.Links;
foreach (var link in links.Where(l => l != null && (l.Text.Contains("Select Account")| l.Text.Contains("Monthly Statement"))))
{
    link.Click();
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you or not.